# JS template not rendered by Ruby on Rails on Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, render

I deployed my app to a staging app on Heroku. It works 100% fine locally.

http://exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com

I have two controllers that render JS. When I submit a remote form, its invoking the intended action and executing the code within... except it is not rendering a JS template. Database changes within the action are being made, but that is where the app stops. It is happening to both controllers that render JS. Keep in mind that the app works correctly in dev mode locally.

I'm wondering if the issue lies with the configuration of my app to work with Heroku?

Here is my log for the Heroku app:

```
2013-02-01T20:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.230.151.152 at 2013-02-01 20:17:17 +0000
2013-02-01T20:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered blurbs/_show.html.slim (2.3ms)
2013-02-01T20:17:12+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:10)
2013-02-01T20:17:12+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:10)
2013-02-01T20:17:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e staging -p 23436`
2013-02-01T20:17:15+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
2013-02-01T20:17:15+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2013-02-01T20:17:15+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:23436, CTRL+C to stop
2013-02-01T20:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 232ms (Views: 114.2ms | ActiveRecord: 63.0ms)
2013-02-01T20:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2013-02-01T20:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered business_hours/_index.html.slim (24.9ms)
2013-02-01T20:17:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/index.html.slim within layouts/application (78.4ms)
2013-02-01T20:17:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/foundation/orbit/left-arrow-5a8ccc07cfa3eae4292d7c705fc7b0a2.png host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=5ms connect=18ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=522
2013-02-01T20:17:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/foundation/orbit/right-arrow-6fca0c667c001b2352c44c9fb1e55528.png host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=2ms connect=7ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3242
2013-02-01T20:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-6cd756f9981b294d6c6bd575ae87f94b.css host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=59ms service=15ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-02-01T20:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/orbit_05-c6ea9ca2a7468ee90a6c8bfc87eb607e.jpg host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-02-01T20:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/orbit_03-42632d5ec29efd0b5e4c8cae7336e47c.jpg host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-02-01T20:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/orbit_02-64cae3654d21289ce3fe325715c395ed.jpg host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-02-01T20:31:29+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/blurbs/1 host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=7ms service=167ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-02-01T20:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-ca9f839e91c53f606b8c9344a4a1243e.js host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-02-01T20:31:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=exposehair-staging.herokuapp.com fwd=68.230.151.152 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=8ms connect=16ms service=148ms status=200 bytes=30683
```

And my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

# Gems required by all environments
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'                     # https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on
gem 'carrierwave'                             # https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave
gem 'combined_time_select', '~> 1.0.0'        # https://github.com/excid3/combined_time_select
gem 'fog', '~> 1.3.1'                         # https://github.com/fog/fog
gem 'font_awesome', '~> 3.0'                                # https://github.com/balexand/font_awesome
gem 'foundation_rails_helper',                  # https://github.com/sgruhier/foundation_rails_helper
  :git => 'git://github.com/sgruhier/foundation_rails_helper.git',
  :branch => 'master'
gem 'mini_magick'                             # https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick
gem 'rack-canonical-host'                     # https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host
gem 'redcarpet'                               # https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet
gem 'roboto'                                  # https://github.com/LaunchWare/roboto
gem 'slim-rails'                              # https://github.com/leogalmeida/slim-rails
gem 'sorcery'                                 # https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery
gem 'stamp'                                   # https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp
gem 'validates_email_format_of'               # https://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of

# Gems requred only for development
group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors'                         # https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors
  gem 'binding_of_caller'                     # optional dependancy of better_errors
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Gems required for heroku
group :staging, :production do
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  gem 'compass-rails'                                         # https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails
  gem 'zurb-foundation'                                   # http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/
end
```

I also have the following set in my application.rb file:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

UPDATE: Here is some relevant code as requested. No js templates are rendered on Heroku, but they fully work locally. That is why I initially omitted it.

one example:

controllers/blurbs.rb

```
class BlurbsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login

  # PUT /blurbs/1
  def update
    @blurb = Blurb.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @blurb.update_attributes(params[:blurb])
        format.js { }
      else
        format.js { render 'reload' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

views/blurbs/reload.js

```
# Reload form
$("#editBlurb<%= @blurb.id %> form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:blurb => @blurb}) %>")
```

views/blurbs/_form.html.slim

```
= form_for blurb, remote: true do |f|
  .field
    = f.text_area :content, :label => blurb.name.titleize
  .actions = f.submit 'Save'
```

Comment: How about some relevant code? (your controller action, the Javascript template, the path of the template, etc...)

Comment: I didn't think that information was necessary since it works locally... but I will add it anyways. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: I'm offering $10 payable via paypal to the first person who can tell me how to fix my app. Video recording here: https://vimeo.com/59312693

Comment: I see the JS template throwing a 500 in your logs: "... method=POST path=/blurbs/1 ... status=500 ...". Try turning up your log level in production and see if you can get any more useful data out of that.

Comment: Also, you can eliminate sources of errors by making your dev and production envs as similar as possible. As Dominic shows, the POST is failing - which does a bunch of database stuff (as well as render JS). For example, I see you're using sqlite for development. Highly recommend you use the exact same database locally - databases are subtly different from each other, even if you think you're just using standard SQL.  Finally, look at using Rails 3.2.11 instead due to [some security considerations](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/).

Comment: @JonMountjoy I updated to rails 3.2.11, good catch. Been so many security updates lately, I lost track.

Comment: @Dominic Thank you so much for telling me to "turn up the log level". A quick search led me to config.log_level = :debug, which yields a log similar to dev.

Answer (score 4):

I turned the log level to debug

```
# staging.rb
config.log_level = :debug
```

and noticed the following:

```
Started PUT "/blurbs/1" for 68.230.151.152 at 2013-02-11 00:26:26 +0000
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by BlurbsController#update as JS
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rXyxUFU5qhjR4YieynLVAnr5ADnaUXn+No4Qruw5CFo=", "blurb"=>{"content"=>"# About us\r\n\r\nTell **your story** here."}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"1"}
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 318ms
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template blurbs/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim]}. Searched in:
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/roboto-0.1.0/app/views"
2013-02-11T00:26:26+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

Rails on Heroku was only looking for js, html, erb, builder, or slim. Not coffee script. Then I remembered that coffee script was in my assets group in my gemfile. It coffeescript gets pre-processed on heroku, but the gem must not be available to run with the app. So I moved the gem outside the assets group and my app now works perfectly on Heroku!

Since @Dominic's answer led me there, contact me with your paypal if you wish to claim the $10 I offered for resolving my issue. I really appreciate it. Thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704688/keil-miller

Comment: Haha - no Paypal necessary. Just happy to help someone get their problem solved :)

Comment: Interestingly, you titled the JS template "views/blurbs/reload.js" in your question. Is the file actually named "views/blurbs/reload.js.coffee"?

Comment: Thank you. And yes, it's actually .js.coffee. I guess I forgot that in the title. However, the code is indeed coffeescript. No semi-colons! :)